# Room fallbackToDestructive срабатывает каждый раз

Tags: android, kotlin, room

Знакомлюсь с Room и пытаюсь собрать небольшой проект читая базу из папки ASSETS. 
Столкнулся с таким вопросом: 
При однятии версии базы данных выкидывает исключение и просит добавить МИГРАЦИЮ.
Мне же достаточно просто перезаписывать базу из ассетов при поднятии версии.
В доках для этой цели есть метод **`fallbackToDestructiveMigration()`**
Но когда я указываю его в билдере по факту моя база данных перезаписывается при каждом старте приложения.
Что мне нужно - ЧТО бы база перезаписывалась из ассетов **только** при поднятии версии приложения.
и я не пойму как добиться такого поведения. Буду благодарен за помощь.

Вот как я все делаю:

Это простейший пример.

```
@Dao
NameDao
@Insert(entity = Name.class, onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
void insertMe(Name name);
```

Далее база данных:

```
  @Database(version = 2, entities = [Name::class])
abstract class AppDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun nameDao(): NameDao
}
```

POJO

```
    @Entity(tableName = "tips_of_the_day")
data class Name(
    @ColumnInfo(name = "name")
    var name: String?
) {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "_id")
    var id: Int = 0
}
```

Application

```
class App : Application() {
private lateinit var appDatabase: AppDatabase


override fun onCreate() {
    super.onCreate()
    appDatabase = getAppDatabase()
}

 fun getAppDatabase(): AppDatabase {

    return Room.databaseBuilder(
        this,
        AppDatabase::class.java, DATABASE_NAME
    )
        .createFromAsset("database/tips_of_the_day.db")
        .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
        .allowMainThreadQueries()
        .build().also { appDatabase = it }

}

companion object {
    private const val DATABASE_NAME = "tips_of_the_day.db"
}
```

}

Ну и вот как вычитываю:

```
val db: AppDatabase = (application as App).getAppDatabase()
    val dataBase = db.nameDao()


    textView.setOnClickListener(){
        val name: Name = Name( "Anton")
        dataBase.insertMe(name)
        val tableSize: Int = dataBase.all.size
        toast("db size  : $tableSize")
        Log.d("TAG" , "db size  : $tableSize")
    }
```

Получается что код работает до момента перезапуска приложения и потом база затирается на дефолт(

Comment: А что у вас с версий БД в assets?

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja база данных там не меняется. Пока просто лежит одна версия.

Comment: Думаю нужно поднять версию базы в ассетах - она же как ни крути отличается от требуемой в коде. А вообще не очень понятен смысл - вас не устраивает, что сохранённые данные затираются после перезапуска, а то что всё нажитое непосильным трудом затрётся после обновления нормально?

Comment: Как ее поднять в ассетах? У меня стоит version = 1. И происходит ровно все то же самое. Смысл да, все правильно, перезатираться при перезапуске она не должна. Должна перезатираться только при поднятии версии. У меня база содержит расписание которое не меняется по сути никогда. Но в некоторых случаях нужно вносить изменения.

Comment: @woesss вообще , если честно не могу дорубить почему он перезаписывает ее каждый раз.

Comment: У вас скорее всего вот этот сценарий срабатывает, только миграции с 1 на 2 нет, поэтому все и затирается. https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/prepopulate#ex-multistep

Comment: КАк мне реализовать миграцию таким образом, что бы данные при поднятии версии попросту перезаписывались?